# Error Occurred: The number of results does not match the number of interviews that were executed in a single bulk execution request

Tags: apex, visual-workflow

I have a simple flow which is calling a apex action whenever an account is updated

[image]

My apex action looks like this

```
@InvocableMethod(label='Invoke Sanitize Email Ids' Description='This method will call sanitizeEmailIds method')
    Public static List<List<String>> invokeSanitizeEmailIds(List<String> queueList){
        List<List<String>> retString=new List<List<String>>();
        List<String> ret1=new List<String>{'a','b','c'};

        retString.add(ret1);
        return retString;
    }
```

When i am running the flow for 1 record it works fine, but when multiple accounts are updated together i am getting this error

Error Occurred: The number of results does not match the number of interviews that were executed in a single bulk execution request.

Can anyone suggest a resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only returning 1 list no matter how many you receive in the queue list as if two accounts are updated it will invoke this with 2 strings and expect 2 lists with a,b,c in it's return

```
    @InvocableMethod(label='Invoke Sanitize Email Ids' Description='This method will call sanitizeEmailIds method')
    Public static List<List<String>> invokeSanitizeEmailIds(List<String> queueList){
    List<List<String>> retString=new List<List<String>>();
    for(String s : queueList){
        retString.add(new List<String>{'a','b','c'});
    }
    return retString;
    }
```

this will return 2 lists rather than 1